# How do I mimic missing properties or elements in JavaScript objects or arrays?

Tags: javascript, properties

Assume we're getting purchase order data in form of a JavaScript object:

```
{
    purchaseOrder: {
        orderDate: {
            year: 1999,
            month: 10,
            day: 20
        },
        shipTo: {
            country: "US",
            name: "Alice Smith",
            street: "123 Maple Street",
            city: "Mill Valley",
            state: "CA",
            zip: 90952
        },
        billTo: {
            name: "Robert Smith",
            street: "8 Oak Avenue",
            city: "Old Town",
            state: "PA",
            country: "US",
            zip: 95819
        }, /* ... */
    }
}
```

If we know that shipping address is present we can access its ZIP code via the following expression: `data.purchaseorder.shipTo.zip`.

Now if we're *not* sure if shipping address is present, we start jumping through hoops. We basically have to check the existence of the property on the each step.

The same thing about setting the value. If `data` does not have `purchaseOrder` yet, then we can't just do `data.purchaseOrder.shipTo.zip = '90952'`, can we?

But if we know in advance that `purchaseOrder` *may* have a `shipTo` property, is it somehow possible to "mimic" missing properties? So that `data.purchaseorder.shipTo.zip` would just return `undefined` instead of throwing a type error?

And vice versa, would it be possible for `data.purchaseorder.shipTo.zip = '90952'` just create intermediate objects?

I was thinking about using getters and setters for the task, but I'm not sure if both `data.purchaseOrder` and `data.purchaseOrder.shipTo` may be `undefined` at the same time.

Does anyone know a better way to approach this?

My goal is clearly to reduce the overhead of checking the existence of intermediate properties.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Javascript proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Common_mistakes_and_misunderstanding) a proposed feature of ES6.  This allows you to handle requests for any arbitrary property that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a getter and setter for the data object, that takes a string to specify the properties:

```
data.get = function(path){
    var p = path.split('.');
    var o = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if (!o.hasOwnProperty(p[i])) return;
        o = o[p[i]];
    }
    return o;
};

data.set = function(path, value){
    var p = path.split('.');
    var o = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!o.hasOwnProperty(p[i])) {
            o[p[i]] = {};
        }
        o = o[p[i]];
    }
    o[p[i]] = value;
};
```

Usage:

```
data.set('purchaseorder.shipTo.zip', 90952);
var zip = data.get('purchaseorder.shipTo.zip');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/b22xfkk3/

Comment: This means that all your code has to use strings for data paths.  Yes, it can be made to work (this question has been examined many other times here on SO), but IMO it make for really ugly code for ALL the accessing of the data - not to mention a lot slower to execute.  I'd be surprised if this was actually the cleanest way to write the overall code.

Comment: This is the direction I was thinking about - but combined with property getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have these options:

1. You precondition the data so it's easier to access and all intermediate objects you rely on are guaranteed to exist.
2. You create a function that manages testing each piece of that path for you to avoid creating errors and return whatever default value you want if any part of the path doesn't exist.
3. You test every single piece of every path that might not exist before you use it.  This generally involves using an access function that accepts a path as a string such as `getValue("purchaseorder.shipTo.zip")` and a function that they breaks apart that string and accesses it one piece at a time.  This changes the way you write ALL the code that accesses the data to go through this function and executes significantly slower.
4. You use exception handling to catch the paths that don't exist and cause errors.
5. In ES6, you could use a proxy to intercept requests for properties that do not exist and provide a default behavior.

It is my opinion that preconditioning (perhaps on a copy of the data) leads to the easiest code for accessing the data.  You combine all your code in one place to make sure that any data path you plan to access exists and perhaps even has a decent default value.  Then, when you write the code to use this data, you don't have to worry about intermediate objects not existing and the access code can be simple and reliable.

---

Here's a function that will make a copy of your original data, then precondition it to have all fields/values that are present in a shellPrototype data structure.  I have used code like this for reading settings from a settings file and then merging in default values for missing properties.

```
// recursive function to clone an object. If a non object parameter
// is passed in, that parameter is returned and no recursion occurs.
function clone(obj) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }

    var temp = obj.constructor(); // give temp the original obj's constructor
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

// takes as input an unknown data structure and a shellPrototype
// it guarentees that everything that is in the shellPrototype and
// returns a copy (original data is not modified)
// This also assumes no circular references
function preCondition(orig, master) {
    // start out by making a deep clone of the original data
    var copy = clone(orig);

    function iterate(data, shell) {
        if (typeof shell === "object") {
            for (var prop in shell) {
                if (shell.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if (typeof data[prop] === "undefined") {
                        data[prop] = clone(shell[prop]);
                    } else if (typeof shell[prop] === "object") {
                        iterate(data[prop], shell[prop]);
                    }
                    // throw an error if data contains mismatched type from shell
                    if (typeof data[prop] !== typeof shell[prop]) {
                        throw new Error("typeof data in orig does not match typeof data in master for property name = " + prop);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    iterate(copy, master);
    return copy;
}

// the shell contains all intermediate objects and/or leaf values 
// that you want to make sure exist in the conditioned data
var shellPrototype = {
    purchaseOrder: {
        orderDate: {},
        billTo: {zip: 99999},
        shipTo: {},
        poNumber: 1,
    }
};


var data = {
    purchaseOrder: {
        poNumber: 98765,
        billTo: {}
    }
};
var conditionedData = preCondition(data, shellPrototype);
console.log(conditionedData);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ktj01euf/

Comment: `var data = {}; data.purchaseorder.shipTo = data.purchaseorder.shipTo || {};` produces a type error. I have to do it on every level, exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: *I don't know the extent of your logic...* - purchase order is just an example, the question is more in general.

Comment: And I don't actually want to actually *change* the data of the object. Only "mimic" on access.

Comment: @lexicore - now you've added a bunch more requirements to your question.  Please go back and clarify EXACTLY what you want.  Are you asking about the case when any level in your data structure might be missing?  See the four options I've added to the end of my question.  You're going to need to pick one of those or combine pieces of them into a new combination

Comment: FYI, preconditioning can be done on a copy of the data if you don't want to change the original.  IMO, preconditioning leads to the simplest use of the data.  You combine all your code in one place that fixes up a copy of the data structure to make sure that everything you plan to reference exists at least in some default condition.

Comment: I was asking about missing intermediate properties (in plural, i.e. many things may be missing) and "mimicking" (i.e. just "pretending" it is there). But you're right, the wording is not unambiguous.

Comment: @lexicore - FYI, if `data.purchaseorder` doesn't even exist, then you should short circuit that at a much higher level because your code shouldn't be accessing `.shipTo` fields if there is no order to ship in the first place.  My original answer assumed that you already knew that `data.purchaseorder` exists before you tried to access `.shipTo` fields.

Comment: @lexicore - In Javascript, there is no clean way to use syntax like `data.purchaseorder.shipTo.zip` without risking throwing a TypeError if an intermediate piece doesn't exist.  You can preflight all the intermediate pieces of the path, create a function that you pass each piece of the path to independently so it can check each piece of the path or you can catch an exception and handle it if it is thrown.

Comment: Checking many/higher levels is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. But I think you're right, preconditioning is probably the only viable way.

Comment: @lexicore - FYI, this issue has been discussed many times before here on StackOverflow if you feel like spending some time searching to find those answers (I wasn't immediately sure what to search for myself), but I have seen previous discussions.

Comment: *In Javascript, there is no clean way to use syntax like data.purchaseorder.shipTo.zip without risking throwing a TypeError if an intermediate piece doesn't exist.* I am not sure about that. A property getter may do a lazy init.

Comment: @lexicore - My comment was addressed at using code like this:  `var zip =  data.purchaseorder.shipTo.zip` (native Javascript syntax).  How would you put a property getter on a piece of the path that doesn't exist since that is the whole issue right?  I'd like to see how you do that and how that would be less work and less complication than just preconditioning a copy with intelligent defaults.

Comment: This should be possible with classes. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/lexi/ke1xr06d/) what I got so far.

Comment: @lexicore - I thought you said you didn't want to modify the object.  And, you'll have to code an accessor for every possible intermediate object.  Interesting academic exercise (you could write your own answer to your question if you want).  But, do you really think this is the cleanest way to solve your problem that makes the easiest to understand and use and maintain code?  How do you think it will perform?

Comment: I'd argue that no modifications were made to the object on the access. What was changed? It's not an answer as `data.purchaseOrder` and `data.purchaseOrder.shipTo`  aren't `undefined`. I'm just exploring and asking as I'm no up to latest language features. You might be well right about preconditioning. But exploration may give further options. Maybe not exactly as I want it, but this is a way to learn.

Comment: @lexicore - If you started with a real object with some data in it that you were going to apply your getters idea to, you would have to call `Object.defineProperty()` on the real data object which would add properties to it (thus modifying it).  It sounds like you will like this article: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/04/22/creating-defensive-objects-with-es6-proxies/

Comment: @lexicore - I added a precondition function to my answer that outputs a fully conditioned copy.  It takes the original data and a shellPrototype data structure as input.  One thing that makes this very easy to maintain is the shellPrototype is an easy to understand and edit representation of what you want to make sure is there.  It can hold either objects, arrays or leaf values.